# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on different hard drives

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, hard-drive, 16.04, windows-10

I have a UEFI boot. I have three hard drives, one SSD two normal HDDs, the problem is that I want to dual boot Windows 10 (installed on the SSD) and Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 on a 600GB HDD, installing goes pretty well, but it doesn't detect my Windows 10 drive.

Answer (score 0):

First, is your Ubuntu in EFI mode ?
You can check with this

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo BIOS
```

I do not think it can detect EFI boots if it is in BIOS mode.